# Применить функцию ко всем дивам в блоке

Tags: javascript

Сразу скажу чтобы в дальнейшем не было вопросов. Вроде "А что так уже не делают?!, разве нельзя просто сделать вот так?! и т.д". В js я полный нуб. И естественно сформировать свой вопрос я не могу(Так сам бы нагуглил)

В чем весь сабж. Есть код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var margin = $("#image1").width() / 2;
  var width = $("#image1").width();
  var height = $("#image1").height();
  $("#image2").stop().css({
    width: '0px',
    height: '' + height + 'px',
    marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
    opacity: '0.5'
  });


  $("#reflection2").stop().css({
    width: '0px',
    height: '' + height + 'px',
    marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px'
  });
  $("#image1").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      width: '0px',
      height: '' + height + 'px',
      marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
      opacity: '0.5'
    }, {
      duration: 500
    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#image2").stop().animate({
        width: '' + width + 'px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '0px',
        opacity: '1'
      }, {
        duration: 500
      });
    }, 500);
  });
  $("#image2").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      width: '0px',
      height: '' + height + 'px',
      marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
      opacity: '0.5'
    }, {
      duration: 500
    });
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#image1").stop().animate({
        width: '' + width + 'px',
        height: '' + height + 'px',
        marginLeft: '0px',
        opacity: '1'
      }, {
        duration: 500
      });
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="vizitka">
  <img id="image1" src="" />
  <img id="image2" src="" />
</div>
<div class="vizitka">
  <img id="image1" src="" />
  <img id="image2" src="" />
</div>
```

Сейчас все эффекты применяются только к первому диву vizitka(ко внутренним изображениям).  А таких дивов на странице несколько. Как сделать, что бы функция применялась к каждому image1,image2 Которые лежат в vizitka. Я думаю нужно id поменять на класс...НО нужно что-то еще. Все мои попытки оказались тщетными(

Comment: Использование двух элементов с одним id категорически запрещено.

Comment: @alvoro. Я же написал, что наверное нужно заменить.Тут все ясно что использовать нельзя....тут еще надо как то получать их не по иду, а по индексу...но я не знаю как

Comment: У вас только две картинки в блоках visitka будет? Если да, то вам и классы не надо:

    $('.vizitka > img').eq(0) // 1 картинка
    $('.vizitka > img').eq(1) // 2 картинка

Я так понял ваш код работает только для первого div-а?

Comment: @alvoro.Да 2 картинки и еще один span.Да работает только на первом диве. Если не трудно-то напишите весь код в Ответ, а не в комментарий.Я повторюсь.Я полный нуб.+ заодно отмечу правильный ответ

Comment: @HoPkInS, [Публичное самоунижение не заменяет выполнение домашних заданий](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте

```
var doNicely = function (this_) {
  var $imgs = $('img', this_),
  $img1 = imgs.eq(0),
  $img2 = imgs.eq(1);

  var margin =$($img1).width()/2;
  var width=$($img1).width();
  var height=$($img1).height();

  $($img2)
    .stop()
    .css({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'});

  $("#reflection2")
    .stop()
    .css({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px'});

  $($img1).mouseover(function(){
      $(this)
        .stop()
        .animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $($img2)
          .stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
      },500);
  });
  $($img2).mouseout(function(){
      $(this)
        .stop()
        .animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $($img1)
          .stop()
          .animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
      },500);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.vizitka').click(function () {
    doNicely(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*
$img2.stop().css(
{
    width:'0px',
    height:height+'px',
    marginLeft:margin+'px',
    opacity:0.5
});
*/
var width=$("img.image1").width();
var height=$("img.image1").height();

$("div.vizitka").hover(function(){
    var $vizitka=$(this);
    $vizitka.find("img.image1").animate(
    {
        width:'0px',
        height:height+'px',
        opacity:0.5
    },400,function()
    {
        $vizitka.find("img.image2").animate(
        {
            width:width+'px',
            height:height+'px',
            opacity:1
        },400);
    }
    );
},function(){
    var $vizitka=$(this);
    $vizitka.find("img.image1").stop();
    $vizitka.find("img.image2").animate(
    {
        width:'0px',
        height:height+'px',
        opacity:0.5
    },400,function()
    {
        $vizitka.find("img.image1").animate(
        {
            width:width+'px',
            height:height+'px',
            opacity:1
        },400);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `+'px'` не нужен, насколько помню.  
upd. а вот отбивать пробелами и не переносить открывающую фигурную скобку для читаемости кода - нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//-------------------------
/*
*  @Cache------------------
*/
var margin,
    width,
    height;

var viz = $('.vizitka');
var i = 0;
//-------------------------

// viz.find('img').stop().css({
//     width:'0px',
//     height: height +'px',
//     marginLeft: margin +'px',
//     // opacity:'0.5'
//   });


var autoassignment = function(f){

        this.f = f;

        while(f > -viz.length){

              var vizOnly = $(viz.get( f ));
              var b = vizOnly.children('img');

              margin  = $(b.get(0)).width()/2;
              width   = $(b.get(0)).width();
              height  = $(b.get(0)).height();

              // mouseover ________________________________
              $(b.get(0)).mouseover(function(callback){

                          var self = $(this);

                          self.stop().animate({

                                  width:'0px',
                                  height: height + 'px',
                                  marginLeft: margin +'px',
                                  opacity:'0.5'

                          },{duration:500});

                          window.setTimeout(function() {

                                        self.stop().animate({

                                                width: width + 'px',
                                                height: height + 'px',
                                                marginLeft: '0px',
                                                opacity: '1'

                                        },{duration:500});

                          },500);
              });

              // mouseout ________________________________
              $(b.get(1)).mouseout(function(callback){

                          var self = $(this);

                          self.stop().animate({

                                  width:'0px',
                                  height: height +'px',
                                  marginLeft: margin +'px',
                                  opacity:'0.5'

                          },{duration:500});

                          window.setTimeout(function() {

                                      self.stop().animate({

                                              width: width + 'px',
                                              height: height + 'px',
                                              marginLeft: '0px',
                                              opacity:'1'

                                      },{duration:500});

                          },500);
              });

              // $(b.get(1)).stop().css({
              //     width:'0px',
              //     height: height +'px',
              //     marginLeft: margin +'px',
              //     opacity:'0.5'
              //   });

          f--;
        }
  };

  autoassignment( i );

}); //document ready
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <style>

  .vizitka img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  </style>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://starta.ru/assets/new/img/blog/JScript.png"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var margin  = $("#image1").width()/2;
  var width   = $("#image1").width();
  var height  = $("#image1").height();

    // $("#image2").stop().css({width:'0px',
    //     height: height +'px',
    //     marginLeft: margin +'px',
    //     opacity:'0.5'
    //   });


  vis = $('.vizitka');
  var i = 0;

  while(i < vis.length){

    var visOnly = $(vis.get(i));
    var b = visOnly.children('img');

    var margin  = $(b.get(0)).width()/2;
    var width   = $(b.get(0)).width();
    var height  = $(b.get(0)).height();
        $(b.get(0)).mouseover(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                self.stop().animate({width:'0px',
                    height: height + 'px',
                    marginLeft: margin +'px',
                    opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});

                window.setTimeout(function() {

                    self.stop().animate({width: width + 'px',
                        height: height + 'px',
                        marginLeft: '0px',
                        opacity: '1'},{duration:500});
                },500);
        });

        $(b.get(1)).mouseout(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                self.stop().animate({width:'0px',
                    height: height +'px',
                    marginLeft: margin +'px',
                    opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});

                window.setTimeout(function() {

                    self.stop().animate({width: width + 'px',
                        height: height + 'px',
                        marginLeft: '0px',
                        opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
                },500);
        });



        // $(b.get(1)).stop().css({width:'0px',
        //     height: height +'px',
        //     marginLeft: margin +'px',
        //     opacity:'0.5'
        //   });

    i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <style>
  /**{
    border: 1px solid black;

  }*/
  .vizitka img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  </style>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="vizitka">
      <img id="image1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
      <img id="image2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Первые в ряду картинки зацикливаются при переворачивании.